# No exact matches in call to subscript , If I use forEach, does not work

Tags: swift

Please check the attached code below.
Why Pattern raise Error? , "No exact matches in call to subscript"

What is the difference between A and B?

This is the text import from the console.

```
3
Everest 8849
K2 8611
Kangchenjunga 8586
```

This is code

```
struct Mountain {
    let name: String
    let height: Int
}

func highestmountain() {
    var mtList = [Mountain]()
    let N = Int(readLine()!)!
    (0..<N)
        .forEach { _ in
            
            /* Pattern A */
            readLine()!
                .split(separator: " ")
                .forEach {
                    mtList.append(Mountain(name: "\($0[0])", height: Int("\($0[1])")!)) //  Error: No exact matches in call to subscript
                }
            
            /* Pattern B */
            let reads = readLine()!
                .split(separator: " ")
            mtList.append(Mountain(name: "\(reads[0])", height: Int("\(reads[1])")!)) // works!
            
        }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pattern A, you're using `split(" ")` which creates an array of `String`s (or, more specifically, `String.SubSequence`), and then you call `forEach` on that array.

`forEach` calls the attached closure for *each item* in the array. So, with your second input line, for example, on the first `forEach`, `$0` will be "Everest" and on the second call, it'll be `8849`. However, in your code, you're attempting to get `$0[0]`, but `$0` is not an array -- it's a single `String.SubSequence`. Thus the error about the subscript.

Your second approach (Pattern B) works because `reads` *is* an Array of `String.SubSequence`, so using a subscript (ie the `[0]`) works.

*Unrelated to your question, but it's worth noting that using subscripts like `[1]` will fail and crash the app if you haven't first checked to make sure that the array has enough items in it. Force unwrapping with a `!` (like you do with `Int(...)!`) can also cause crashes.*

Comment: than you so much!!  I understand! Thank you for your help. Thank you very much.